# Acess violation ao criar Thread

Tags: delphi, thread, delphi-7

Estou recebendo o erro:

> Acess violation at address 00420214. Write of address 0000000E.

Ao criar uma Thread. A linha do erro é exatamente a linha da criação(marcada com '>').
Em `uses` eu adicionei a Unit3(a thread)
Em `var`, eu defini:

```
DownThread : TMeuDownloader;
```

E então, em um clique do botão, defini:

```
>DownThread := DownThread.Create(True);
DownThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
DownThread.Priority := tpNormal;
DownThread.Resume;
```

E a thread:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TMeuDownloader = class(TThread)
  private

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation
uses Unit1;
procedure TMeuDownloader.Execute;
begin
end;

end.
```

Mesmo a thread estando vazia, dá o erro.

Comment: O erro dá antes de usar o "Resume".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Onde você escreveu

```
DownThread := DownThread.Create(True);
```

o correto é

```
DownThread := TMeuDownloader.Create(True);
```

Observe a diferença: no seu código você chama o método `Create` a partir da variável em vez de chamá-lo a partir da classe.

Como a variável não contém instância de coisa alguma mas, ao invés, contém apenas uma referência inválida (a variável não foi inicializada), o método falha ao tentar buscar uma instância a partir desta referência inválida.

Além disso, não use o método **Resume** para iniciar a thread. Ao invés, use o método **Start**.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
DownThread := TDownThread.Create(True);
DownThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
//DownThread.Priority := tpNormal; se é prioridade normal, não precisa informar.
DownThread.Start;
```